# Querying a High Cardinality Field

Tags: index, performance, optimization, nosql, cassandra, query-performance

I am designing a data model for our orders for our upcoming Cassandra migration. An order has an orderId (arcane UUID field) and an orderNumber (user-friendly number). A getOrder query can be done by using any of the two.

My partition key is the orderId, so getByOrderId is not a problem. By getByOrderNumber is - there's a one-to-one mapping b/w the orderId and the orderNumber (high-cardinality field), so creating a local secondary index on each node would slow down my queries.

What I was wondering was that I could create a new table with the orderNumber as the partition key and the orderId as the only column (kind of a secondary index but maintained by me). So now, a getByOrderNumber query can be resolved in two calls.

Bear with me if the above solution is egregiously wrong, I am extremely new to Cassandra. As I understand, for such a column, if I used local secondary indices, Cassandra would have to query each node for a single order. So I thought why not create another table that stores the mapping.

What would I be missing on by managing this index myself? One thing I can see if for every write, I'll now have to update two tables. Anything else?